# Rotating rectangle graudally to a maximum rotation point

Tags: rotation, sfml

The code below rotates a rectangle around the origin to -90 degrees when `R` is pressed and to 40 degrees when `A` is pressed.

However, I want it to rotate gradually to -90 or 40 degrees, i.e. each time I press `R` it moves gradually to -90 degrees where it stops, and if I press `A` it will move gradually in the opposite direction to 40 degrees where it stops.

Right now it's working, but when I press `R`, the rectangle jumps directly to the -90 degrees position, and when I press `A` the rectangle jumps directly to the 40 degrees position.

How can I change this behaviour?

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
int main(){

    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(640, 480), "Use 'q','w','a','s','z' & 'X' to move the are");
    sf::RectangleShape rect(sf::Vector2f(100,10));

    rect.setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);

    rect.setPosition(200, 300);
    rect.setOrigin(20, 20);
    rect.setSize(sf::Vector2f(160, 40));

    while (window.isOpen()){

        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event)){

            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::R)){

            rect.setRotation(-90);
        }
        else if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::A)){
            rect.setRotation(40);
        }

        window.clear();
        window.draw(rect);
        window.display();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to rotate clockwise every time you press R but stop rotating when you get to -90 degrees?

Comment: Yes, basically each time i press A it gradually movie towards the -90 where it stops and the same from 0 to 40 and also from -90 to 40. I think i have to use velocity of 1.0 or so, each time i press A it movies towards the -9 by 1.0 velocity

Comment: Right now it jumps from the origin to -90 and so on.

Comment: I believe so. Just one more question: Do you want the rectangle to move when you DO NOT have your key pressed? Like do you want to press R once and the thing gradually moves or do you only want it to move each time you press the R?

Comment: No, the rectangle should only move i press A OR B . So each time i press A it movies towards -9 degrees by velocity of 1.0 or so, and the same for the 40 degree. SO ONLY WHEN I PRESS R OR A.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need a variable to determine the speed of rotation; you said you wanted it to be ~1.0. We can make use of the `setRotation`, `rotate`, and `getRotation` functions to make the rest very easy:

```
float velocity = 1.0;
while (window.isOpen())
{
    sf::Event event;
    while (window.pollEvent(event))
    {
        if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
            window.close();

        if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::R))
        {
            if (rect.getRotation() > -90)
                rect.rotate(-velocity);
        }
        if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::A))
        {
            if (rect.getRotation() < 40)
                rect.rotate(velocity);
        }
    }

    window.clear();
    window.draw(rect);
    window.display();
}
```

As you can see the `rotate` function rotates the rectangle the number of degrees you specify. `setRotation` however sets the rectangle's rotation to immediately be the specified angle instead of rotating the rectangle frame by frame.

Comment: but when i press the A why does it rotate 360, instead it should stop at -90, and the same for the 40 degree rotation.

Comment: So the -90 is the limit for it to rotate and 40 also